# CSS Styling Placeholder of Input Does Not Seem To Be Working

Tags: html, css, forms, input, placeholder

I'm new to CSS and I wanted to add some margin-right to the placeholder of an input:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control search-engine" placeholder="Search this blog">
</div>
```

And this was my try on setting margin-right:

```
.search-engine ::placeholder{
     margin-right:5px !important;
     padding-right:5px !important;
}
```

But it didn't make any changes somehow!

So how to properly make changes and style the placeholder of an input in CSS?

Comment: you can't style margin or padding.. what do you want to achieve? why you don't syle the padding inside the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Padding or Margin From "Placeholder". and add in the input tag. like this

```css
.input-group input{
  padding:10px 20px;
}
.search-engine::placeholder{

}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control search-engine" placeholder="Search this blog">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it. Your structure should be like this:

```
<label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
   <span class="placeholder">Search this blog</span>
</label>
```

then you can process your label text:

```
label {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-control::placeholder{
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control search-engine" placeholder="Search this blog">
</div>
```

Comment: this won't work you can't style the padding of placeholder pseudoelement